# wmd-rails in production doesn't show images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wmd, wmd-editor

I have a problem with wmd-rails, when I'm trying rails server in production enviroment, It doesn't show images from wmd-rails gem, JS and css show properly everything, where can be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with compiling your images, at least try to add in production.rb (general):

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

or specify path:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(path/to/image.png)
```